# invalid_grant when hash password identity server 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, password-hash

I have config like this

```
public class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients(string[] originUris, string[] redirectUris, int tokenLifetime, int slientRefreshToken)
        {
            return new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "eFMS",
                    ClientName = "eFMS Services",
                    AccessTokenLifetime =  tokenLifetime,
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
                    RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,
                    SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = slientRefreshToken,
                    RedirectUris = redirectUris,
                    AllowedCorsOrigins= originUris,
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        "openid", "profile", "offline_access", "efms_scope"
                    },
                }
            };
        }
        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
        {
            return new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource("efms_api", "eFMS D&T API")
                {
                    ApiSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) }
                }
            };
        }
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
        {
            return new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile() { Required = true },
                new IdentityResource()
                {
                    Name = "efms_scope",
                    Description = "eFMS D&T API",
                    DisplayName = "eFMS D&T API",
                    UserClaims =
                    {
                        "userId","workplaceId","userName","email"
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

and when I test in postman with username:admin, pass: 123456 return token
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSWFi.png)

but if I hash password the result is "invalid_grant" and when I debug code, not excute in 
*Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)* function. Please help me resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are configuring IdentityServer's `AddTestUser` then ResourceOwnerPassword grant password validation is implemented in `IdentityServer4.Test.TestUserResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` and the password is compared in plain text (**no hashing**) in `TestUserStore.ValidateCredentials`:

```
    public bool ValidateCredentials(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = FindByUsername(username);
        if (user != null)
        {
            return user.Password.Equals(password);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Regarding debugging `IdentityServer4.Test.TestUserResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.ValidateAsync(...)` have you unchecked "Enable Just My Code":

[image]

If you are using your own implementation of `IdentityServer4.Validation.IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` then whether the password needs to be hashed is up to you.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I relize the reason is password encoded. I use RSA to encrypt it, used public key 1024 bit. So after I use 512 bit, I resolved this problem. The config identity is not a cause of it.